# using PlayStateChange event to loop the song in MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, winforms, media-player

I'm trying to implement the code that will loop current song countless times.

That's my code:

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if (e.newState == 8) // media ended
    {
        if (repeat)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = 0;

            //axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.previous();
            //axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.playItem(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem);
        }
    }
}
```

setting `currentPosition = 0` is working fine if I debug the code on the next line.

But after debug - new event is triggered(event 9(Transitioning) followed by event 3(Playing)) and the next song starts to play!

how do I prevent this from happening?

basically that is what happening right now:

- event 8 triggered (Media End)
- set position 0
- event 9 triggered (Transitioning)
- event 3 triggered (Playing)

**Edit:** after messing around with my code I have finally managed to break the chain of Event changes.

```
public bool ended = false;
public WMPLib.IWMPMedia latest_song;

private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if (ended)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.playItem(latest_song);
        ended = false;
        return;
    }

    if (e.newState == 8) // media ended
    {
        if (repeat)
        {
            ended = true;
            latest_song = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if the code can get any better than this..

Answer (score 1):

```
bool ended = false;
bool skipnext = false;
bool skipnextnext = false;
bool skipextra = false;

private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if (ended)
    {
        skipnext = true;
        ended = false;
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.playItem(latest_song);
        return;
    }

    if (e.newState == 6) // buffering
    {
        skipextra = true;
    }

    if (e.newState == 8) // media ended
    {
        if (repeat)
        {
            if (currect_album.Songs.Count < 2) { return; }
            ended = true;
            latest_song = current_song;
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (e.newState == 3) // playing
    {
        // these "skips" are necessary for scenario: "repeat: on", "click: next"
        if (skipnext) { skipnext = false; skipnextnext = true; return; }
        if (skipnextnext) { skipnextnext = false; return; }
        // Buffering adds 1 more skip! Ask Microfost why ;)
        if (skipextra) { skipextra = false; return; }

        current_song = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem;
        // your stuff
    }
}
```

- the first solution worked fine for half a day ;)
- the second solution worked for "repeat", but did not work in case if user clicked "next"
- the third and final (I hope) solution finally works in situations when "repeat" is needed, plus it skips the song if "next/prev" command is triggered!
- the fourth edition! added extra "skip" if buffering kicked in.. Buffering messed up my code a bit, but now it's all working. Additionally, I've added "1 song in a playlist" checker.

P.S. Microsoft coders - if you see this post - please, add "on_next" and "on_previous" status! Thanks